# How to remove null value and filled by the next Column Value

Tags: ssis, null

I am loading data from multiple source to a destination table using SSIS . The destination table only have 5 Columns but we have 11 value (Columns) need to load. So I load into second row and Third row with the same ID .

The Question is not every ID have 11 value , Most of them less than 11 . So there are Null and 0 Amount in the table . The requirement is we have to use the value name and Amount in order . For example if Value Amount3 = Null . Then we should use ValueName 4 and ValueAmount4 to fill ValueAmount3 and ValueName3.

Column Name 
ID  |ValueAmount1 |ValueName1 |ValueAmount2 |ValueName2 |ValueAmount3 |ValueName3 |ValueAmount4 |ValueName4 |ValueAmount 5 |ValueName5

Any suggestions will be appreciate !

Answer (score 0):

Load all the data into a staging table, and then use a stored procedure to populate the final table from the staging table, and use COALESCE in the stored procedure to replace NULLS with other columns, like `COALESCE(ValueAmount3, ValueAmount4)`